# How to Manage User Modifiable Lookup Tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, lookup-tables

There is a table in our database that acts very much like a standard lookup table (ID, Description).  However, this particular one is not static, the client wants the ability to add entries on the fly.  Some entries that will come pre-populated are "special" in that there will be code that checks for them (various business rules).

Normally, I'd create the table without auto-incrementing IDs so I can be safe in the knowledge that the enum that mirrors the entries in the table always match.  Then it's just a matter of checking if this object's ID matches up with the enum value I'm checking for.

I could attempt the same approach, with IDs that don't auto-increment and an enum that only covers the entries that aren't added on the fly.  We would shortly run into the issue of coming up with the next ID when the user adds a new entry.  Basically re-implementing in code the database's auto-increment feature.

If I switch to using identity columns, there'd be the whole issue of getting out of sync with the enum values.

Of course I could always match on the textual 'Description' attribute but that's bad for obvious reasons.

Is there a nice way to deal with something like this?  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186736/best-way-to-implement-many-to-many-lookup-table-with-user-entered-data) doesn't really answer it for me.

Comment: What are you going to do with the enum when a user adds a record to the table?

Comment: Nothing.  That's one of the drawbacks.  The enum won't reflect new values, only the ones they've come up with at deployment time.  Obviously if a new one requires special code, a redeployment will be required.

Comment: What are the "obvious reasons" that make matching on description bad? If it's just the nature of changing descriptions then you can still use a textual "code" for your built-in items

Comment: It'd have to be hardcoded in the application and exist in the database.  They're rather long and formatted description that have a chance of changing.  It's not the end of the world, just another drawback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the solutions given here, there is always the possibility to use a completely meaningless identity for all your lookup foreign keys but also have a column which links the lookup to your enum values for business logic:

```
lkpTable
PK Identity
Description
FK LogicEnum NULL

lkpLogic
PK EnumValue
LogicParamColumns
```

In this case, the logic is provided and not altered by users.  New lookups can even be routed to use any existing logical rules - so you can have different settings which behave the same way as existing hardcoded business rules, but display differently.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use two tables?  One table holds your ENUM values that you code for.  The other handles all user configurable items.

Unless that is you are creating new enums based on the client entered values as well.  If that's the case why don't you migrate your primary key to a GUID and use a static class with static string members (kind of like a virtual ENUM).  Then you would not need to worry about uniqueness as the guids are much harder to duplicate unless you do it on purpose.

We use the GUID psuedo enum approach as we have to maintain multiple copies of the same database and they can easily get out of sync.  The guids help in that regard.

Comment: Using multiple tables prevents the use of foreign keys to those look-up tables

Comment: not necessarilly, it would just mean more work as you would need a relationship table inbetween to handle both lookup tables (not pretty but possible).  However I would still recommend the GUID approach as it's much easier to consolidate multiple databases with deseperate data without having to worry about primary key changes.  Then the user/client can do whatever they want and they don't have to worry ever about ID overlap.  On top of that it keeps him from doing the description match which is what he does not want to do it sounds like.

Answer (score 2):

1) Assign a range to your client that is larger than the number of values your application will ever need, say 1000000. Add a trigger to enforce only allowing new values above that range.

2) Use auto-increment and generate your enums off your local copy of the database.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Mitch's answer:

You can seed the identity column with the large value and when you're populating the table with the predetermined identities, you can set identity insert on.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_1
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1000000, 1),
    Label nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
)  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Table_1 ON
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Table_1(ID, Label) VALUES (1, 'First');
INSERT INTO dbo.Table_1(ID, Label) VALUES (2, 'Second');
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, that smells like one concern servicing two different requirements.

I would separate it into two tables, something like ApplicationLookups and CustomLookups, and  then it would be intuitive to treat them differently in code and also from a DB perspective.

Comment: Using multiple tables prevents the use of foreign keys to those look-up tables